# Conditionally replace all values in a column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like so:

```
eh1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
eh2 <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
mydata <- data.frame(eh1, eh2)
```

What I want to do is replace all values of `1` in `mydata$eh1` with `0` AFTER the value of `1` in `mydata$eh2`. This is ultimately what I want the data to look like:

```
eh1 <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
eh2 <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
mydata2 <- data.frame(eh1, eh2)
```

I do not want an answer specific to the rows and columns of the example data, but more general code I could apply in something like a `dplyr` pipeline or `for` loop.

I think this is an easy one but for some reason I'm having trouble! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the values to 0 where `eh1 = 1` and the row number is after the first occurrence of 1 in `eh2`.

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  mutate(eh1 = replace(eh1, row_number() > which(eh2==1)[1] & eh1 == 1, 0))
  #mutate(eh1 = replace(eh1, row_number() > which.max(eh2) & eh1 == 1, 0))
  #mutate(eh1 = replace(eh1, lag(cummax(eh2) > 0 & eh1 == 1), 0))
  #mutate(eh1 = replace(eh1, lag(cumsum(eh2) > 0) & eh1 == 1, 0))


#  eh1 eh2
#1   1   0
#2   1   0
#3   1   1
#4   0   0
#5   0   0
#6   0   0
#7   0   0
#8   0   0
```

The same can be translated in base R :

```
transform(mydata,eh1 = replace(eh1,seq_along(eh2) > which.max(eh2) & eh1 == 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
     mutate(eh1 = +(row_number() <= match(1, eh2))  )
#  eh1 eh2
#1   1   0
#2   1   0
#3   1   1
#4   0   0
#5   0   0
#6   0   0
#7   0   0
#8   0   0
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
mydata$eh1 <- +(seq_len(nrow(mydata)) <= match(1, mydata$eh2))
```